# Why isn't Volley isn't returning any information from an API?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm unable to retrieve JSON from the TFL(Transport for London) API using Volley.  I've tested my code with a different API and all works perfectly.  The API URL is working fine - I have tested the URL with Postman.  Logcat isn't showing and red errors..  Please see code & logcat below.

```
 tempTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);

    String url = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Victoria";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // tempTextView.setText("Response: " + response.toString());

                    Log.e("status", "Response: " + tempTextView.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONObject statusJSONObject = response.getJSONObject("lineStatuses");
                        String status = statusJSONObject.getString("statusSeverityDescription");
                        tempTextView.setText(status);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

      // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

logcat  (UPDATED)

10-31 19:24:10.410 18618-18618/com.example.aaron.itube E/TAG: Error response:
                                                              com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"northern","name":"Northern","modeName":"tube","disruptions":[],"created":"2017-10-31T10:48:22.99Z","modified":"2017-10-31T10:48:22.99Z","lineStatuses":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":0,"statusSeverity":10,"statusSeverityDescription":"Good Service","created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","validityPeriods":[]}],"routeSections":[],"serviceTypes":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","name":"Regular","uri":"/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Regular"},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","name":"Night","uri":"/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Night"}],"crowding":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
                                                               Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":"northern","name":"Northern","modeName":"tube","disruptions":[],"created":"2017-10-31T10:48:22.99Z","modified":"2017-10-31T10:48:22.99Z","lineStatuses":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","id":0,"statusSeverity":10,"statusSeverityDescription":"Good Service","created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","validityPeriods":[]}],"routeSections":[],"serviceTypes":[{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","name":"Regular","uri":"/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Regular"},{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities","name":"Night","uri":"/Line/Route?ids=Northern&serviceTypes=Night"}],"crowding":{"$type":"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
                                                                  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
                                                                  at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
                                                                  at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Maybe implement `onErrorResponse`??? And see the error??? Also I hope you're using Android Studio as development tool

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Done as suggested.  I've edited the question to include the current logcat output. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start write some code in the `onErrorResponse` method to log the errors received like the following:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Error response:", error);

}
```

Then update and post the errors in your question.

**UPDATE**

From the updated logcat here is the clue `of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`. The response you receive is of type `json` `array` and not `json` `object`. So change your call to:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // place your code here, mind now this is a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject`

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error response:", error);

            }
        });
   // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   queue.add(jsArrayRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Done as suggested.  I've edited the question to include the current logcat output. Cheers.